# unable to use strcmp function

Tags: php, drupal

Newbie in PHP.
I'm getting a value of an array index in my variable as `$acc_type = $cur_account['roles']`
I'm printing the output by `echo $acc_type` and it prints `administrator` on screen.

So, if I tried `echo strcmp("administrator", $acc_type);` and it should ideally print `0`, but it isn't; instead it is printing `1`.

I'm not able to understand why this happens. Do I need to do a typecast or something? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @SLAYER this is completely false. strcmp gives you 0 when equal: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Comment: @SLAYER: int strcmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 ); strcmp returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.

Comment: sorry my mistake... :) 

proper behaviour ..
Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2 ; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2 , and 0 if they are equal.

Comment: probably offtopic: the element is called `roles` - plural. How are multiple roles stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing the content of your variable using [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net/var_dump) to see why `strcmp` does not return `0`.

`var_dump` will print the quoted string as well as the length, which helps finding white space characters or whatever prevents the string from being equal.

Comment: yes, I get `string '<div class="item-list"><ul><li class="first last">administrator</li>
</ul></div>' (length=80)` when I do var_dump

Comment: Well, that explains why the strings are not equal, I guess. It seems to me, that the content of your variable is intended for presentation only or you did something wrong. There should be no HTML in there if it's purpose is to hold the role of the user.

Comment: I just gave you +135 reputation ;-) (Just kidding) you deserve it!

Comment: and I was trying this on Drupal, not just plain PHP. Have to study deep in order to get this :)

Answer (score 1):

[`strcmp`](http://php.net/strcmp) is actually a basic function to compare string. You can just use `==` (or `===` which is safer) to test equality between strings.

```
if ($acc_type === "administrator") {
  // Your code
}
```

But, if strcmp returns 1, your strings are definitely not identical. You should check string length (maybe leading/trailing spaces?) with `strlen`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that one of your 'administrator' strings may have a whitespace character in it. 
Use strlen() to ensure they are both the same length.

Using this code :

```
<?php 

$cur_account['roles'] = 'administrator';
$acc_type = $cur_account['roles'];
echo $acc_type . "<br>";
echo strcmp("administrator", $acc_type);

?>
```

I was able to output

```
administrator
0
```